# Header Image stops repeating when window is resized

Tags: html, css, header, resize, repeat

So i have an image in stuck to the top of my page that repeats all the way across the top. For some reason when I resize the window and then scroll over to the right it stops repeating. The div is the first in the document outside of the wrapper. Any ideas?

```
#header {
    background-image:url('http://daveywhitney.com/img/paperhead.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
    height: 145px;
    margin:0 0 20px 0;

}
```

Comment: can you please point a link to a working example?

Comment: @Frankie StackOverflow has the same problem, as well as ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MattRockwell the trick to solve it is to apply the CSS rule "fixed" that would, however put the DIV *always* on display. On SO that would simply not work. What currently happens with SO is that the TOP-BAR is sized to the view-port with a with of 100%, were you to size the TOP-BAR to the BODY it would run along nice all way long.

Take a look into CSS `fixed` property.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine in FireFox. Check the width of the parent element when you resize the window.

Answer (score 0):

The available benchmarks as set by your code are:-

- width - 100% (so full width of the image is taken into consideration)
- "background repeat - x" - Image will repeat horizontally

Internally, say the width of the image be 250px & the width of your full browser screen be 1024px. So technically, the image will repeat horizontally at least 5 times, with 4 times in full size & the last one will be shown a little bit.

Now, if you resize the browser or view the same web page in a pop-up window, your browser screen is bound to have its width modified. Let's say that now your browser screen width is 220px. As the image width is greater than the browser screen width (in this particular test case), so the image will not repeat at all, & you will also not be able to see the full image.

It's not that there is any bug, it's just the logical part, which we need to understand.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from the details you have provided but here is a answer that might do the trick. Add the following

```
#header {
    background-image:url('http://daveywhitney.com/img/paperhead.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
    height: 145px;
    margin:0 0 20px 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative}

#wrapper {width:960px;margin:0 auto;position:relative}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `min-width` to be slightly larger than your main content.